# php is_int: evaluate data from cookies and GET

Tags: php, cookies, get

Why does this piece of code returns false?

```
$var_1 = $_COOKIE['cookie_value']; // = 15
$var_2 = $_GET['get_value']; // = 21

echo $var_1 . '<br>' . $var_2;
/* output: 
15
21
*/


var_dump(is_int($var_1));
echo '<br>';
var_dump(is_int($var_2));
/* output:
bool(false)
bool(false)
*/
```

Comment: Yes maybe, but there's nothing about cookies in that question and my Q&A started from searching something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because cookies and $_GET always return a string data type.
To use `is_int()` on such data just add a zero to `$var` to parse it to number. Hence:

```
$var = $_GET['get_value']; // 15
var_dump(is_int($var));
// output: bool(false)

$var += 0;
var_dump(is_int($var));
//output: bool(true)
```

Comment: Or use `is_numeric($var)`. On the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) of `is_int()` it says "To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric()."

Comment: Yes but doing so you won't understand if that's an integer. My method saves you an "if".